# Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ & C# - How to set "strictOrderDispatch" true on IDestination Queue?

Tags: c#

How can I set the "strictOrderDispatch" property to true on an IDestination Queue?(In C#, using Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ (version 1.2), (and preferably in code and not XML)).

Background: I'm trying to deploy a consumer to a machine with multiple network interfaces and I keep getting an error:

Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.BrokerException: javax.jms.InvalidClientIDException : Broker: Production - Client: Blahblah.Production already connected from '[one of the other IPs on the same machine]'

(maybe I can get around this if I can specify different clientIDs for each IP, but no idea how to do this either)

Googling for this and I see a page that talks about ["Per Destination Policies"](http://activemq.apache.org/per-destination-policies.html)

but I can't find any examples of how to do this in C#.
Closest I see is a page here:
http://activemq.apache.org/nms/examples.html
that shows

```
IDestination destination = SessionUtil.GetDestination(session, "queue://FOO.BAR");
```

but nothing about setting any other queue specific properties.

Any ideas how to set "strictOrderDispatch" true on an IDestination Queue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having such a face-palm moment.  These settings are specified using querystring syntax.

I guess when stumped I should've been looking at JMS docs too.  I finally clued in as I read the Uri Format here: 
http://camel.apache.org/jms.html

`jms:[queue:|topic:]destinationName[?options]`

Answer (score 0):

Per-destination settings are made at the broker-side.  The NMS C# client does not support destination options, per se. You actually set options on the consumer.  So for example:

`queue://FOO.BAR?consumer.DispatchAsync=true&consumer.nms.OptimizeAcknowledge=true`

This technically configures the consumer, but accomplishes what you are looking to do.

Also, `strictOrderDispatch` is not a consumer side option, as it doesn't make sense. It would be inconsistent to have some consumers request it and others not request it. It should properly be a server-side only setting.